# React, Redux - Fetch data after updating via api call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I am using react with redux and typescript, Trying to add item from react via api call which returns back whether it is success or failed.

So I fetch data from componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadData());
}
```

And from the actions layer I add item like below

```
static addItem = (Item: IAddItemRequest): Promise<number> => {
            return Promise.resolve(
            AI.addItem(Item).then((ItemData) => {
                return ItemData;
            }).catch(error => {
                return error;
            }));
        }
```

So how can I loadData after Adding an Item

Also AddItem doesn't change in the state

Answer (score 0):

A possible soln can be opted using two actions, 1 that add item and second that load data.

```
export const loadData = (ItemData) => {
    return {
        type: LOAD_DATA,
        payload: ItemData
    };
};

export const addItemAction = (Item) => {
    return dispatch => {
        addItem(Item).then(ItemData => {
            dispatch(loadData(ItemData));
        });
    };
};
```

Above both are inter linked redux actions and we have to call first action in react component's componentDidMount method as follow

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(addItemAction(Item));
}
```